# How can I click on first button with data-cy equal to other buttons?

Tags: angular, testing, cypress, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm new to test e2e and I'm trying to click on a specific button, I gave it a data-cy that automatically is been attributed to other buttons created dynamically.

How can I click on first button? The code i use for click on a single data-cy is this:

```
When('I click on button data-cy:{string}', (element) => {
  cy.get('[data-cy="' + element + '"]').click();
});
```

Thanks for attention

EDIT

Already tried to add .first() on line, but i would like to use a method that allowed me to use the selector also for only the second/third... button. Btw for the specific test the .first() syntax works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eq(0)` for this.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="' + element + '"]').eq(0).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, you're suggestion works perfectly. Just readed the doc better and i could have avoided the question.. Thanks a lot!